# Clustering: if my features are all in 0-1 range do i still have to use standard scaling

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis

I am trying to run clustering algorithm on a dataset with 14 features. Of those features, except for one, every feature lies between 0 to 1. The remaining one feature is a continuous variable between 0 to 8000. Do i need to use the standard scaler on all the features or just this one feature ( 0 - 8000) before clustering?? OR do i just use the min-max scaler for this one feature alone??

Answer (score 0):

You don't "have" to use either.

Standard scaling as well as [0;1] scaling (which is *not* the same) are just two popular *heuristics* for weighting variables. Neither is "correct*.

If you have a better reason to weight variables differently, you may as well just do that. Things don't get more "correct" by scaling.

Reducing the weight of that 8000 variable likely is a good idea. But if that question arises, it probably means you have not understood the problem that you are trying to solve... You are just using a huge, without a plan.